# Memory leak in Valgrind using new

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

The example may be bad but this is how it looks when I trace the stack frame which Valgrind shows. The LocationList, Location, FolderList and Folder are different classes and I have pasted only the copy constructors and assignment operators of these classes. But I am unsure why there is a memory leak.

I understand that I am using new operator and a for loop in copy constructor which could be the cause of trouble but I am unsure how to handle this. Here is the call stack from Valgrind.

```
==15733== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 28 of 1,002
==15733==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==15733==    by 0x54FA25: FolderList::operator=(FolderList const&) (Folder.h:63)
==15733==    by 0x54FD8A: Server::operator=(Server const&) (Server.h:22)
==15733==    by 0x550631: Location::operator=(Location const&) (Location.h:44)
==15733==    by 0x5507AC: LocationList::LocationList(LocationList const&) (Location.h:76)
==15733==    by 0x54988C: VPSyncInterface::login(std::string, std::string, VPStatus*) (vpsync.cc:365)
==15733==    by 0x549AD5: VPSyncInterface::connect(std::string, std::string, VPStatus*) (vpsync.cc:382)
==15733==    by 0x548FF0: VPSyncInterface::reconnect(VPStatus*) (vpsync.cc:227)
==15733==    by 0x548D39: VPSyncInterface::initialize(VPStatus*, int) (vpsync.cc:175)
==15733==    by 0x42E5B4: ProcessImageImpl::ProcessImageImpl(char const*, int, char const*, int) (ProcessImageImpl.cc:172)
==15733==    by 0x426FDD: cvRetrievalImpl::getProcessObject(cvRetrieval::ProcessType, char const*, int, char const*, int) (cvRetrievalImpl.cc:70)
==15733==    by 0x426B4A: main (ThinIMAGEd.cc:727)
```

Below is the code stack:

```
cvRetrievalImpl.cc
    69   case cvRetrieval::PROCESS_IMAGE:
    70     return new ProcessImageImpl (application_class, instance_wants_to_access_vp, auth_group, threadCount);
    71     break;

ProcessImageImpl.cc

    VPStatus init_status;
    if (syncInterface->initialize (&init_status) != 0)
    {
        cvLog (CV_LOG_FATAL, "Cannot initialize VP sync interface: %s", 
                    init_status.interpret_current_status());
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        

vpsync.cc            
    364     LogonXMLParser* parser = new LogonXMLParser ();
    365     AddDtd *aDtd = new AddDtd (application_class);
    366     string logonOutputXML = aDtd->add (out_xml, process);
    367    
    368     LocationList *vp_locations;
    369     vp_locations = parser->doParse ((const XMLByte*) logonOutputXML.c_str (), logonOutputXML.size ());
    370     delete aDtd;

    378     if (locations)
    379         delete locations;
    380     // We have to make a private copy of the locations returned by the parser,
    381     // because the parser's copy will disappear when the parser is destroyed.
    382     locations = new LocationList (*vp_locations);
    383     delete parser;


LocationList& operator= (const LocationList& list)
    79             {
    80             if (this == &list)
    81                 return *this;
    82             incr = list.incr;
    83             curr_size = list.curr_size;
    84             curr_capacity = list.curr_capacity;
    85             if (locations)
    86                 delete [] locations;
    87             locations = new Location[curr_capacity];
    88             for (unsigned int i = 0; i < curr_size; i++)
    89                 locations[i] = list.locations[i];
    90             return *this;
    91             }

Location.h
    39         Location& operator= (const Location& location)
    40             {
    41             if (this == &location)
    42                 return *this;
    43             locationName = location.locationName;
    44             server = location.server;
    45             servers = location.servers;
    46             return *this;
    47             }

Server.h
    16         Server& operator= (const Server& server)
    17             {
    18             if (this == &server)
    19                 return *this;
    20             serverName = server.serverName;
    21             folder = server.folder;
    22             folders = server.folders;
    23             return *this;
    24             }

Folder.h

    54         FolderList& operator= (const FolderList& list)
    55             {
    56             if (this == &list)
    57                 return *this;
    58             incr = list.incr;
    59             curr_size = list.curr_size;
    60             curr_capacity = list.curr_capacity;
    61             if (folders)
    62                 delete [] folders;
    63             folders = new Folder[curr_capacity];
    64             for (unsigned int i = 0; i < curr_size; i++)
    65                 folders[i] = list.folders[i];
    66             return *this;
    67             }

    16         Folder& operator= (const Folder& folder)
    17             {
    18             if (this == &folder)
    19                 return *this;
    20             folderName = folder.folderName;
    21             folderDesc = folder.folderDesc;
    22             return *this;
    23             }
```

Comment: You allocate a new object with `new` and never deallocate it with `delete`. Using `new` can normally be avoided anyway with modern C++ by using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. If you cannot use these, you’ll have to make sure every object you allocate, is deallocated eventually.

Comment: I presume there is a member field of `FolderList` class named `folders`. Is it `delete`d in `~FolderList()`? Are all `FolderList`s, in turn, destructed?

Comment: The restriction is I cannot use C++11 in my code having unique and shared pointer things. As gcc doesn't support this.

Comment: `As gcc doesn't support this.` well gcc supports it, your version (which might be unlikely), compiler flags, or the environment you develop for  (which could be the case if you do embedded development) might not support it.

Comment: The destructor is deleting folders ~FolderList ()
            {
            if (folders)
                delete [] folders;
            folders = NULL;
            }

Comment: The destructor is being called? Do you have any leaks referring to the FolderList object?

Comment: Karan, you wrote "I have pasted only the copy constructors and assignment operators". I can see only assignment operators, and no constructors. In general, prefer containers that manage storage for you, as suggested by @PaulFloyd.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have many leaks (`loss record 28 of 1,002`).

First, a minor thing. In C++ you don't need to check that a pointer is non-NULL before deleting it. So

```
if (folders)
    delete [] folders;
```

can be replaced by

```
delete [] folders;
```

Next, you say that you can't use smart pointers. It would be even better if you could use standard library containers.

So instead of defining `folders` as a pointer to `Folder` and writing

```
if (folders)
   delete [] folders;
folders = new Folder[curr_capacity];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < curr_size; i++)
    folders[i] = list.folders[i];
```

you could define `std::vector<Folder> folders;` (instead of `Folder* folders;` which is what I presume you have currently) and write

```
folders = list.folders;
```

Other benefits of this:

1. No need for you to manage the vector's memory.
2. No need for curr_size and cur_capacity - std::vector provides these

Comment: Thanks the other leaks are possibly leaks, that I'll check later.I tried this and it says "error: no match for 'operator=' in 'folders = list->FolderList::folders'

Comment: Valgrind (at least memcheck) has a low rate of false positives. The leaks are ordered by increasing size, so I recommend starting with the ones are the end of the list.